# how to use UIAppearance appearanceWhenContainedIn:

Tags: ios5, custom-controls

I notice that in iOS5 we can custom UIKit control by `UIAppearance` and I start to use it.

I'd like to use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to custom the `UINavigationBar`'s  `tintColor` in different class, for example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[A class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[B class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

However, it totally doesn't work. And I tried to add property in Class A/B like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *tintColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

It seems workless too.

Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: For the other UIKit controls, like UIButton, it works. But UINavigationBar doesn't work. May do matter with the containment.

Comment: Your example works fine for me (A and B are two different UINavigationController subclasses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I attended the ios5 talk and asked this question.
Just like [yakovlev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118721/yakovlev) refers, it's a good idea to subclass the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I have subclassed the UINavigationController but the [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[A class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; is not working yet, should I do any other configuration?