# Subclass UINavigationController's BarButtonItems

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

There doesn't seem to be a way of subclassing just the navigation bar's `UIBarButtonItem`s other than to use the appearance proxy - but this changes the appearance of all `UIBarButtonItem`s in the application.

I want to be able to set subclass of each of these buttons to a custom one, in order to set their tint colour.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try appearanceWhenContainedIn: method of UIAppearance Protocol?

Comment: Had no idea that method existed! thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Nagan said, you can use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`

an example is here: [uiapperancewhencontainedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290981/how-to-use-uiappearance-appearancewhencontainedin)